# Apply different header styling to different ag-grid instances in one app

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid in my application and have two grids on the same page. I would like to make the text label for the header in one grid vertical and the other grid horizontal.

Here's a doc showing how to make header vertical for one grid. 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/#textOrientation

```
.ag-cell-label-container {
  /*Necessary to allow for text to grow vertically*/
  height: 100%;
}

.ag-header-cell-label {
  /*Necessary to allow for text to grow vertically*/
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
  /*Force the width corresponding at how much width
    we need once the text is laid out vertically*/
  width: 55px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.ag-header-cell-label {
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 90px;
  padding-top: 36px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: #1b6d85;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {
  /*There is empty space left at the top from the menu and sort
    icons not used*/
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

It added specific styles into styles.scss file. But this will apply globally.

On the other hand, it will not make any changes to text orientation if I add those css into app.component.scss file.

Is there a way to apply css to only one ag grid instance?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case.
 I wrapped each of the grids into different `divs` with different `class` attribute.
Once you style the grid by the class of the wrapping div, Your styles should be encapsulated. Have you tried that ? :)

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution in Angular doc! https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep
Use :host ::ng-deep before the CSS classes, then it will apply to the current component only.

Comment: Cool :) If my answer helped somehow, upvotes appreciated :)